# My last Media Query isn't being used

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Why is the last media query not working here? Am I over looking something? I have tried changing the order but it always leaves out the last one for some reason. This appears to be the correct cascading order to me.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobileBrand {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .desktopBrand {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
  .nav-right {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1106px) {
  .nav-right {
    margin-left: 6em;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have some odd characters in there that I believe mess up the parsing http://i.imgur.com/f01TOc0.png (the red dots). Also can be seen using http://csslint.net/ edit: just to clarify, these don't exist after the first two queries.

Comment: please write your HTML code it seems that you say min-width 768px and max-width 767px.  both of them don't shown in all sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario above doesn't clearly tell the browser what margin-left to apply if screen is less than 1079px - it could be either 6em or 1em.

You should define **min** and **max** values for the **1106px** query.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) and (max-width: 1106px) {

    .nav-right {
        margin-left: 6em;
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

the fourth one will overwrite the third one, since also the fourth one defines everything less than 1106px. So the third will never apply.

Use `min-width` AND `max-width` on the fourth one to avoid that.

ADDITION/EDIT: or just reverse the order of the third and fourth one...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
  .nav-right {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
}​

@media screen and (max-width: 1106px) {
  .nav-right {
    margin-left: 6em;
  }
}​
```

You have two queries that conflict with one another.

One is from 0px to 1079px and the other 0px to 1106px.

They overlap for 1079px altogether.

I would define the queries a little more explicit.

Stating something along the lines of

```
@media screen and (min-width:1080px) and (max-width:1106px)
```

That way, anything above your defined 1079px will show a margin-left of 6em instead.